Duplicate key value violates unique constraint when trying to insert
I'm using drizzle-orm to work on my Postgresql database...
I have this simple table:
export const ExperimentData = pgTable('experiment_data', {
  id: bigserial('id', { mode: 'number' }).primaryKey(),
  timestamp: bigint('timestamp', { mode: 'number' }),
  websiteId: bigint('website_id', { mode: 'number' }),
  experimentId: bigint('experiment_id', { mode: 'number' }),
  variantId: bigint('variant_id', { mode: 'number' }),
  event: varchar('event', { mode: 'string', length: 255 }),
  data: json('data'),
});

and I have a script that reads data from Redis and writes to this table:
await statisticsdb.insert(ExperimentData).values({ timestamp, websiteId, experimentId, variantId, event, data });

this script runs is supposed to run every hour, triggered by a cronjob and now it doesn't run because I get the error
PostgresError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "experiment_data_pkey"
 code: "23505"

      at ErrorResponse (/home/ubuntu/production/pertento/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:792:23)
      at handle (/home/ubuntu/production/pertento/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:811:5)
      at data (/home/ubuntu/production/pertento/node_modules/postgres/src/connection.js:562:3)
      at emit (native:1:1)
      at addChunk (native:1:1)
      at readableAddChunk (native:1:1)
      at data (native:1:1)

this error is caused on the first insertion try.

I haven't done anything, haven't changed the schema or the data in the database
as you can see, the only primary key I have in the table is the id field
am not trying to force the id

I don't know exactly what to do here. Also, don't want to mess up the data in Postgres nor in Redis.
Update
After running
select * from public.experiment_data_id_seq;

I get the value: 253020
looking to the database, the latest ID is 1171578 which is waaaay off.
How can I fix this? Can I just update this value in the database directly?


Look at the Postgres log to see what is actually being inserted. 2) My suspicion is someone/something has done an ALTER on the underlying sequence for the id column and changed the values making new insert id's duplicate previous ones. Do select pg_get_serial_sequence ( 'experiment_data', 'id' ) to get the sequence. Then select * from <the_sequence> to get it's current settings. Add the result to your questtion.


@AdrianKlaver, I updated my question with the relevant data and you're absolutely right

I would want to know how the sequence and ids got out of whack.  I mean is the latest ID the one that is way off and how did it get inserted or has the sequence been changed.  I've had people dump data into tables from other sources and included the other table's IDs so that they (months later) eventually caused a collision like what you've experienced.

@Val, it is easy enough to do if you directly alter the sequence and change the last_value to a lower number.

Well, there is noone to blame but myself haha, i'm a lone ranger here. I probably messed up in some drizzle migration but i don't see how. Will be monitoring this from now on and maybe the answer will come up. Thank you all

this was a specific case, i think. This was a table that existed in another database and i programatically moved it to this new database. What is weird is that it only started failing 2 days ago, but the process ran on this new database for weeks without problem


Then look in the Postgres log from ~2 days ago and search for  experiment_data_id_seq to see if there is anything relevant.  This assumes you have logging set to capture DDL changes. 2) How did you programmatically move it? Maybe the data you moved over had id's >  253020 and when you created the table it started with a sequence last_value of 1 and there where no issues until you started using id's > 253020.


You could look at the timestamp field  for id's < 253020 and see when the id's where inserted to confirm my(and @Val) suspicion.

the timestamp isn't calculated from the insertion date on the database, but as the item has been recorded in redis, which in this case, will be completely different

I'm happy with what was achieved here, i don't think further investigation is required for now. It definitely had to do with the migration from old db to new db and hopefully, this is a one time off. No data was lost. If it happens again, i know how to fix it and i will spend more time investigating it. Thanks a lot


Yes but the timestamp will still be in sequence moving forward and you can see if the matches the sequence of ids something like select id, timestamp from experiment_data order by timestamp desc.  2) I would suggest in the future do something like pg_dump -d <the_db>  ... -t <the_table> -f the_table.sql This will dump the data and the table definition and most importantly SQL set the sequence values properly.



Find who or what changed the sequence and make sure they/it are prevented from doing that again.

Pick a number that is max(id) + 100 or so and do:


BEGIN;

ALTER SEQUENCE  public.experiment_data_id_seq RESTART <above_number>;


ROLLBACK or COMMIT above depending on success or failure.

Thank you so much @AdrianKlaver, it worked
